# Coolbits not working

Tags: nvidia, fan

I want to use coolbits to increase fan speed of my Fermi GPU. 
280.13 driver installed.
Ubuntu 11.10

I edited */etc/X11/xorg.conf* as follows, by pressing Alt+F2 and

```
gksu gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

I get

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 470"
    Option  "NoLogo"    "True"
    Option "Coolbits" "4"
EndSection

Started getting these messages,
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap"
```

So I did this,

```
sudo aptitude install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

terminal,

```
a@z:~$ nvidia-settings -a [gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1

a@z:~$ nvidia-settings -q fans
```

1 Fan on z:0

```
[0] z:0[fan:0] (Fan 0)
```

a@z:~$ nvidia-settings -a [fan:0]/GPUCurrentFanSpeed=80

```
ERROR: Error assigning value 80 to attribute 'GPUCurrentFanSpeed' (z:0[fan:0])
       as specified in assignment '[fan:0]/GPUCurrentFanSpeed=80' (Unknown
       Error).
```

So, it's not working; I can't enter the fan speed percentage. Also from NVidia X Server, there are no fan controls.

http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Nvidia#Manual_Fan_Control_for_nVIDIA_Settings

Comment: Please, add a question to your problem.

Comment: Option "Coolbits" "4" was the problem! 
Needed to use "5" - it then worked via X Server - 
Just accept the NVidia terms and as if by magic a fan slider bar appears.

Comment: Please, add that to the answer and accept it so we know that the thing is done.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the answer from above, so people like me can more easily find the solution...

'Option "Coolbits" "4" was the problem! Needed to use "5" - it then worked via X Server - Just accept the NVidia terms and as if by magic a fan slider bar appears. '

Comment: Accept the NVidia terms, yes, but where?